# How can I maximize the refresh rate of this OLED display?

Tags: integrated-circuit, display, oled

I have a [single-color 1.5" 128x64 transparent OLED display](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/1.51inch_Transparent_OLED) with an integrated [SSD1309 controller](https://files.waveshare.com/upload/9/9c/SSD1309Datasheet.pdf). It came with a small [driver board](https://files.waveshare.com/upload/0/03/1.51inch_OLED_Transparent_Driver_Board_Schematic.pdf) that supports the SPI and I2C interfaces on the chip. I need to refresh this screen as fast as physically possible. SPI would be plenty of throughput for my use case, so I'm mainly asking about hardware.

The details for the frame frequency can be found in section 8.3 of the datasheet, and the refresh cycle is described in 8.5. In phase 1, which lasts 2 ticks of the display clock, all of the pixels are discharged to clear the previous image. In phase 2, which lasts a configurable number of ticks, the pixels are charged to their target voltages. In phase 3, which lasts a constant 65 ticks, current is driven to the pixels to reveal the image.

**Internal Oscillator**

There is an onboard clock F_osc that can be configured to one of 16 distinct frequencies (section 10.16). Unfortunately, the max frequency isn't listed here. Further down, in section 13, there are some limits listed for the onboard clock, but with a note stating the listed speed is based on a default D5h A[7:4] value, which is 1000b, only half way to the maximum. *Should I interpret the min and max here to be D5h A[7:4] = 0000b and D5h A[7:4] = 1111b respectively, or is this simply the amount of variation at the default?*

**Charge Time**

The next issue is the time it takes to charge up each pixel in phase 2 of the refresh cycle. I don't have any intuition for how fast this can be, but I know it can at least be done in 2 default ticks. I'm assuming if I increase the default clock speed too much, I will start running into issues getting to the target voltages. Once this starts to happen, one option would be to increase the number of ticks in phase 2 so that the charge time stays constant. Phase 2 can be stretched up to 15 ticks, so I could theoretically increase the clock speed about 8x the default. If I want to push this even further though, I believe I would need to decrease the maximum brightness so that the charge time is shorter. *What kind of relationship should I expect between target voltage and charge time? For example, would running the display at 50% brightness allow me to double the refresh rate, or is it non-linear?*

**External Oscillator**

Assuming the max clock speed for the onboard clock is indeed capped at the 540 kHz mentioned in section 13, I will need to use an external clock. This is controlled by the CLS and CL pins (section 8.3). I get completely lost in the schematics here. I see the these pins in the die pad drawings (section 5) but they seem to disappear in the pin arrangement diagram (section 6). I'm also not sure if my driver board gives access to these pins. *How can I make use of this feature?*